# Query for documents that do not contain given object in a nested array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a structure like this:

```
{ "id": "object1", "fields": [{"id": 100, "value": "one"}, {"id": 101, "value": "abc"}]}
{ "id": "object2", "fields": [{"id": 100, "value": "two"}, {"id": 101, "value": "cde"}]}
{ "id": "object3", "fields": [{"id": 100, "value": "three"}]}
```

where *fields* are a **nested** datatype.

With a nested query I can get all objects that have a specific value of given field (for example with: field.id = 101 && field.value = "abc" I can get object1).

How can I query for objects, whose *fields* arrays **don't include** given field by its id?

- Example1: I want all objects that do not have a field with id 101 -
  returns object3
- Example2: I want all objects that do not have a field
  with id 102 - returns object1, 2 and 3

What I'm looking for is basically an *exists* query (which I can then negate) that accepts a predicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are dealing with nested documents and you want that if neither of the nested document matches the condition then that document should be considered as a match. If I rephrase this, I can say that do not fetch that document which has a nested document that matches the condition. Translating this to the query dsl,

```
GET <index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "fields",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "fields.id": 101
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I owe you a good beer (or coffee, if you don't drink) ;)
This is precisely what I needed and it seems so obvious now.

Comment: Glad it helped. Thanks for the coffee :)